# Gradle java.util.logging.Logger output in unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, logging, junit, gradle

Sorry, this is probably a very simple question.

I am using [gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) for my development environment. It works quite well!

I have written a simple unit test that uses `HtmlUnit` and my own package.

For my own package, I use `java.util.Logger`.

`HtmlUnit` [seems](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/logging.html) to use commons logging.

I would like to see console output of my logging messages from `java.util.Logger`

However, it seems that even messages at the info level are not displayed in my Unit Test Results GUI (System.err link), although the `HtmlUnit` messages are all displayed.

Please let me know if you have suggestions.

Thank you!
Misha

Comment: One more hint: it seems that if I use a Logger within the actual _test_ class, everything works well. However, my logger is inside the class being tested, and that output does not seem to get processed properly.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I figured it out. It was quite odd.

Namely, if I initialize the logger *outside* of any methods:

```
class foo {
   def log=Logger.getLogger(this.class.name)
}
```

log output is not seen when I write a test.

However, if I initialize the logger *inside* the constructor

```
class foo {
   def log
   foo() {
      log=Logger.getLogger(this.class.name)
   }
}
```

Then it works fine. Odd...

Thank you!
Misha

Answer (score 0):

Bridging logging systems from library's that use their own is complicated. Why not use slf4j's bridging JAR's? They will redirect old calls to commons logging to it's own logging system which YOU design against.

Take a look at http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html

Comment: Thank you. I'm still a bit confused though.

Which logging output can _I_ use that will get displayed in the Unit Test Results?

I mean for my own programs.

Thank you
Misha