# Forward commons-logging messages from tests

Tags: logging, gradle

I have a lot of trouble finding good information on how to get my Logging output displayed when running my junit tests with gradle. To stay Logger-independent, I use Apache commons-logging in my project.

Now I found this, but it doesn't really explain anything: [Gradle java.util.logging.Logger output in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991360/gradle-java-util-logging-logger-output-in-unit-tests)

With http://gradle.org/logging I get a good understanding how to log from gradle tasks, but not how to display the logging messages from my tests.

`gradle -i` is also not what I am looking for. Although that gives me some information about the tests, it does not give me the logging output.

I appreciate any hints in the right directions.

**EDIT** (doing it here since it's quite a long reply to Peter's answer):

Adding

```
test {
testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

worked, kinda. This is a Gradle 1.0-milestone-6 feature, so I first had to upgrade Gradle.
Then, my log4j.properties which was in the src/test/java folder could not be found. Adding

```
sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath += files(sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs)
```

to the build.gradle file at least silenced the warning, but I didn't any logging output. My log4j.xml shouldn't be the problem, it worked in the IDE:

```
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>


<root>
    <priority value="info"/>
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
</root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Just for the sake of completeness, I googled showStandardStream and found the info I should have found to begin with: http://gradle.org/current/docs/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html

Question still open, though, since it didn't seem to work :)

**EDIT2:**

Now `gradle test -i` prints the Logging info output. Although it is not exactly what I was looking for (since it is mixed with the gradle logging), this is good enough.

Answer (score 2):

You could set `test.testLogging.showStandardStreams` to `true` and then make sure that your test logging prints to std out. This will make the logging output appear both on the command line and in test reports.

Comment: thanks for the hint, Peter. See my answer above (was quite long, so I had to place it there).